# Progress on NHibernate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm doing a rather large operation in NHibernate where I kind of sync two databases. This of course takes some time, and it would be nice to present the progress of the operation for the user.

Now the only thing I can present is the status table by table. But it would be good to have a *34/2344 records done* status.

Is this possible in NHibernate (without taking every row individually)?

Comment: You shouldn't use NHibernate for these kind of things, but native SQL instead. Or look at [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102109-1.aspx).

Comment: Well it's rather handy with NHibernate since I can use my standard queries and be sure to get the correct data. Also NHibernate handles the different databases rather good (SQL Server and SQLite)

Comment: In general I would say no. Maybe something can be done using NHibernate event listeners. But you haven't shown what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ProgressInterceptor` class to intercept and report progress like this:

```
var interceptor = new ProgressInterceptor(progress);
var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(interceptor);

var query = session.Query<Entity>()...
interceptor.StartIntercept<Entity>(0, 100, query.Count());
entities = query.Fetch(x => x.Chidren).ToList();
interceptor.StopIntercept();
```

And here is the `ProgressInterceptor`. If you get a StackOverflowException try adding a lock to the progress reporting function.

```
public class ProgressInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    IProgress<int> progress;
    int            count;
    double         start;
    double         end;
    double         factor;
    string         className;
    int?           lastReport;

    public ProgressInterceptor(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public void StartIntercept<T>(double start, double end, int steps)
    {
        count       = 0;
        this.start  = start;
        this.end    = end;
        factor      = (end - start) / steps;
        className   = typeof(T).FullName;
        lastReport  = null;
    }

    public void StopIntercept()
    {
        className = null;
    }

    public override object Instantiate(string clazz, EntityMode entityMode, object id)
    {
        if (className == clazz)
        {
            count++;
            var newReport = (int)Math.Min(start + count * factor, end);
            if (newReport != lastReport)
                progress.Report(newReport);
            lastReport = newReport;
        }
        return base.Instantiate(clazz, entityMode, id);
    }
}
```